# Highchart: Generate Traffic Graph from JSON API

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I'm trying to generate a Traffic Graph with Highchart from my JSON API.
Can someone help me to create the Javascript to create the graph from a json output like this:

[{"id":"1","upload":"767996","download":"3590994","timestamp":1459858309},{"id":"2","upload":"770635","download":"3594895","timestamp":1459858310},{"id":"3","upload":"796561","download":"3707508","timestamp":1459858337},{"id":"4","upload":"799858","download":"3710316","timestamp":1459858337},{"id":"5","upload":"801162","download":"3712063","timestamp":1459858338},{"id":"6","upload":"803541","download":"3713706","timestamp":1459858338},{"id":"7","upload":"805920","download":"3715373","timestamp":1459858338},{"id":"8","upload":"808421","download":"3716762","timestamp":1459858338},{"id":"9","upload":"809305","download":"3717695","timestamp":1459858338},{"id":"10","upload":"810381","download":"3718856","timestamp":1459858338}]

It's possbile to change the API output if it's needed.

Best regards
Leif

Comment: What is a "traffic graph" and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like "Can you do my job, please ?" to me.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo, http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

Comment: This is not an accepted data format for Highcharts. Data formats are explained with examples in [Highcharts API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.data)